# Splitting array using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, split

This is my array buff and I have stored the contents of the array as follows:

```
$buff[0]="3\nHi how are u I am f";
$buff[1]="ine\n The world is so";
$buff[2]="beautiful.\n";
$buff[3]="I love it.";
```

I want to split the array and print as

```
3
Hi how are u I am fine
The world is so beautiful.
I love it.
```

How do I accomplish this? I tried using `split` function like this:

```
my @split_buff=split('\n', @buff);

foreach my $val (@split_buff) {
     print $val;
}
```

But I am not able to split with `\n` as the delimiter, and I need to retain the delimiter as well. What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Do you actually want the blank line between the two outputs (I'm referring to the original way you typed your desired output), or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can simply `print` it.

```
print @buff;
```

Comment: there is space before `The` in `ine\n The world is so` and it seems that is unwanted.

Comment: @mpapec I'm sure OP can get my point and complete it by himself. :)

Answer (score 2):

Join all together and split by `\n\s*`

```
my @split_buff = split /\n\s*/, join "", @buff;

foreach my $val (@split_buff) {

  print "$val\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like answer: "print @buff;". You can also try this code:

```
    $text = ""; # or my $text;
    foreach $line (@buff) { $text = $text . "$line"; }
    print $text;
```